# Maximum depth of given tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, logic

My json structure is like a tree structure.
A non-leaf node has child in svalue attribute of structure JSON object.
A leaf node has the key "executionValueList"

**
In my JSON ,i have two nodes P1,P2 at level 0.
P1 does not have any child. P2 has two children P21 and P22.
P21 does not have any child.
P22 has two child P221 and P222.
P221 has no child and is leaf node.
P222 has two child P2221 and P2222.
P2221 and P2222 have no child and are leaf nodes.
**so maximum no of nodes from root to any leaf node is 4(P2->P22->P222->P2221 or P2->P22->P222->P2222).**

**Script:**

```js
var a = {};
var m = 0;
a[m] = 0;
var counter = {
  "executionList": ["exe1", "exe2"],
  "algoList": [{
    "name": "Algorithm1",
    "paramList": [{
      "name": "P1",
      "executionValueList": [{
        "name": "exe1",
        "value": "v1"
      }, {
        "name": "exe2",
        "value": "v2"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "P2",
      "svalue": [{
        "name": "P21",
        "executionValueList": [{
          "name": "exe1",
          "value": "v3"
        }, {
          "name": "exe2",
          "value": "v4"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "P22",
        "svalue": [{
          "name": "P221",
          "executionValueList": [{
            "name": "exe1",
            "value": "v5"
          }, {
            "name": "exe2",
            "value": "v6"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "P222",
          "svalue": [{
              "name": "P2221",
              "executionValueList": [{
                "name": "exe1",
                "value": "v5"
              }, {
                "name": "exe2",
                "value": "v6"
              }]
            }

          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Algorithm2",
    "paramList": [{
      "name": "P3",
      "executionValueList": [{
        "name": "exe1",
        "value": "v1"
      }, {
        "name": "exe2",
        "value": "v2"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "P4",
      "svalue": [{
        "name": "P21",
        "executionValueList": [{
          "name": "exe1",
          "value": "v3"
        }, {
          "name": "exe2",
          "value": "v4"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "P22",
        "svalue": [{
          "name": "P221",
          "executionValueList": [{
            "name": "exe1",
            "value": "v5"
          }, {
            "name": "exe2",
            "value": "v6"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "P222",
          "executionValueList": [{
              "name": "exe1",
              "value": "v7"
            }, {
              "name": "exe2",
              "value": "v8"
            }

          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

function parameterColumnCounter(counter) {
  var temp;
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(counter.algoList).length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(counter.algoList[i].paramList).length; j++) {
      temp = countInnerParameter(counter.algoList[i].paramList[j]);
    }
  }
  max = temp[0];
  for (n = 0; n < Object.keys(temp).length; n++) {
    if (max < temp[n]) {
      max = temp[n];
    }
  }
  return max
}

function countInnerParameter(parameter) {


  if ("svalue" in parameter) {

    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(parameter.svalue).length; j++) {
      a[m] = a[m] + 1;
      countInnerParameter(parameter.svalue[j]);
    }
  } else if ("executionValueList" in parameter) {
    a[m] = a[m] + 1;
    m = m + 1;
    a[m] = 0;

  }

  return a;

}



alert(parameterColumnCounter(counter));
```

But it is not giving the correct results.I want to find maximum depth of given tree structure. Counter is the Object which stores the entire structure.How to solve the given problem?

Comment: That has to be one of the most generic titles I've ever read. **every** programming question is about coding logic for a particular scenario. Please try to be more helpful to readers.

Comment: ***But it is not giving the correct results*** does not tell us what your problem is or what you want help with.  What exactly is the problem?  What do you observe?  What is the result supposed to be?  To get help here, you need to be very specific about exactly what the problem is.  Remember, we can't read your mind.  We don't know what result you're looking for.  We can only read your words and code.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to understand the data structure of `counter` I hope to have replicated how to reach a solution but it is only loosely based on posted code (no `temp` variable for starters).

A key to understanding the following code is that `paramList` and `svalue` objects have a similar if not the same structure.

```
function findCounterDepth( counter)
{   var maxDepth = 0;
    counter.algoList.forEach( function( algo)
    {   findParamListDepth(algo.paramList, 0);
    });

    function findParamListDepth(paramList, depth)
    {   ++depth;
        paramList.forEach( function (paramObj)
        {   var child = paramObj.svalue || paramObj.paramList;
            if( child)
            {   findParamListDepth(child, depth);
                return;
            }
       });
       maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
    }
    return maxDepth;
}

findCounterDepth(counter);
//= 4
```

---

**Edit**

Adding a count of leaf nodes per algorithm object is uncomplicated. Here the count is added as a `dataLeafCount` property of the algorithm object:

```
function findCounterDepth( counter)
{   var maxDepth = 0;
    var leafCount = 0; // add a leaf counter

    counter.algoList.forEach( function( algo)
    {  leafCount = 0;  // zero leaf count per algorithm object
       findParamListDepth(algo.paramList, 0);
       algo.dataLeafCount = leafCount;  // store as "dataLeafCount" property
    });

    function findParamListDepth(paramList, depth)
    {   ++depth;
        paramList.forEach( function (paramObj)
        {   var child = paramObj.svalue || paramObj.paramList;
            if( child)
            {   findParamListDepth(child, depth);
                return;
            }
            ++leafCount;   // it doesn't have children, increment leaf count; 
       });
       maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
    }
    return maxDepth;
}

findCounterDepth(counter);  //= 4
counter.algoList[0].dataLeafCount; //= 4
counter.algoList[1].dataLeafCount; //= 4
```

Note that if input object immutability needs to be maintained, `findCounterDepth` should be modified to return values in a new data object.

Comment: how to find no of leaf node in given algorithm object?

Comment: Did you ask that in the question? What have you tried?